# How do i use react-habitat with React's Context API

Tags: reactjs

So i'm using react-habitat for non-SPA.

I want to use something like [react-breakpoints](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-breakpoints) which in a normal React SPA, you wrap the `App` component with,

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <ReactBreakpoints breakpoints={breakpoints}>
    <App />
  </ReactBreakpoints>, 
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

But with [react-habitat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-habitat) there isn't something like that.

Comment: I don't see how react-habitat prevents you from wrapping components into other components.

Comment: Cause in my html files/pages, I do not have a single entry point `App`,
from what i understand react-habitat does multiple ReactDOM.render() for each registered component. To pre-wrap them, i would need to do a custom `factory`(https://github.com/DeloitteDigitalAPAC/react-habitat#writing-and-using-custom-factories) for it to wrap <ReactBreakpoints> around my component.

But i believe doing so with in `ReactBreakpoints` case, will create multiple window.addEventListener which i hope not to do

Comment: Why do you need a single entry point? You can wrap your individual components as needed. If you want all your components to be wrapped by default I think you can [write a custom factory](https://github.com/DeloitteDigitalAPAC/react-habitat#writing-and-using-custom-factories) for react-habitat.

Comment: Not sure if you're getting what i mean. I do not want to have the components individually wrapped by `ReactBreakpoints` cause that will create multiple instances of `ReactBreakpoints` window listeners checking on widow size & stuff maybe 10-100 times depending on how many of my components are on screen. So ideally i only need 1 of that instantiated.

Comment: I see. If you want your components to be wrapped by a single instance of `ReactBreakpoints` you may better be using [react portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html). I'm not sure if `react-habitat` allows something similar as I never used it.

Comment: I do not think react portals solves my need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170989/discussion-between-intosite-and-trixn).

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 2**

I just updated the code example with how i think this could work. Note i have not tested this code.

**EDIT**

I just saw your comment that you do not want multiple instances, fair enough. You may want to look at incorporating something like a singleton into my code example below so it always wraps the Module in the same instance: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-singleton

Millage may vary.. I've never tried a singleton component.

---

I'm one of the core maintainers on React Habitat. You can acheive this by creating a custom factory.

eg

**ReduxBreakpointsFactory.js**

```
import { Provider }     from 'react-redux';
import React            from 'react';
import ReactDom         from 'react-dom';
import Singleton from 'react-singleton';
import ReactBreakpoints from 'react-breakpoints';
import breakpoints from './breakpoints';

var ReactBreakpointsInstance = new Singleton(ReactBreakpoints);

/**
 * React Redux DOM Factory
 */
export default class ReduxDomFactory {

    constructor(store = null) {

        /**
         * The redux store
         */
        this.store = store;
    }

    /**
     * Inject the module into the dom wrapped in a redux provider
     * @param {*} module - The component to inject
     * @param {object} props  - The component props
     * @param {node} target - The node to inject to
     */
    inject(Module, props = {}, target) {
        if (target) {
          ReactDom.render(
            <Provider store={this.store}>
              <ReactBreakpointsInstance breakpoints={breakpoints}>
                <Module {...props} />
              </ReactBreakpointsInstance>
            </Provider>
            ),
            target
        }
    }

    /**
     * Dispose of any react instances for a node
     * @param {node} target - The node to tear down
     */
    dispose(target) {
        if (target) {
            ReactDom.unmountComponentAtNode(target);
        }
    }
}
```

**In your bootstrapper file**

```
import BreakpointsFactory from './BreakpointsFactory';

const store = configureStore();
const containerBuilder = new ReactHabitat.ContainerBuilder();

containerBuilder.factory = new BreakpointsFactory(store);
```

Hope that helps ;-) Let me know if you publish this factory and I will put a link to it from React Habitat.

Comment: I will give it a try and report back. Regarding publishing the factory, I'm still quite new to this and don't think I'm capable to do it. Also, i'm already using the Redux factory, how can i add this on top of it?

Comment: I just updated the example with how i think this could work for you.

Comment: I've done this but it doesn't wrap the WHOLE application, just its individual parts...